# Paste two columns separated by a linebreak command that Excel understands

Tags: r, export-to-excel, line-breaks, paste

*How to paste two columns of a dataframe together so that MS Excel will insert a line break between them, when pasted into Excel.*

The result of the code below should look something like this picture when pasted into MS Excel. Notice that the last column has a line break between "Qn1" and "Quebec":

[image]

```
dfExample <- head( CO2 )  ## CO2 is in base datasets

dfExample$Vektor.With.Linebreak <- paste(   df$Plant, df$Type, sep = "(  linebreak here  )" )


write.table( x = dfExample, file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Why not to save as csv and read it from Excel?

Comment: This would not solve the problem of inserting a line break into a cell. The copy-paste part of the question is not essential, it could also have been something like save-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline character sequence for Windows is `\r\n`, so use:

```
dfExample$Vektor.With.Linebreak <- paste(dfExample$Plant, dfExample$Type, sep = "\r\n")
```

Comment: Maybe "linebreak" was too unspecific. What I mean is a linebreak inside the cell, so the number of rows remain the same. Don't know what to call this type of linebreak :)

Comment: @RasmusLarsen Yes, this is what happens when you use the above. You may need to manually adjust row heights to see them in Excel though.

Comment: You are right. I just needed to remember to format the column to wrap text in Excel. Do you know of a webpage(or a google search string) with these types of character sequences?

Comment: @RasmusLarsen "carriage return line feed", it stems from the days of typewriters.